# Microsoft access VBA MsgBox not responding, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, checkout, msgbox

so I have put together an asset check out sheet. There is a Check out button, I want a message to prompt " User ID is required" when it is clicked , if the user ID field is left blank . However, that is not the case with my current code, it just accepts the button click no matter what. Am I missing something here ? (code below)

```
Private Sub CHECK_OUT_BUTTON_Click()
    If (IsNull(Me.USER_ID)) Then
        MsgBox "User ID is required."
    Else
        If Me.Status.Value = "Checked Out" Then
           MsgBox "This device is currently in use."
        Else
            If (Me.Status.Value = "Available") And (Not IsNull(Me.USER_ID)) Then
                Me.Status.Value = "Checked Out"
                RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
                Me.Requery
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: if you change the first line of the `If` condition from `If(IsNull(Me.USER_ID)) Then` to `If(IsNull(Me.USER_ID) or Me.USER_ID = "") Then` does it work?

Comment: For the future you can see what is happening her if you put a breakpoint on the IF statement and hover over `Me.USER_ID`. You'd see then that it is an empty string and not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the User ID field was not registering as `NULL` and was instead just an empty string.

Changing the line:

`If(IsNull(Me.USER_ID)) Then`

To:

`If(Nz(Me!USER_ID.Value) = "") Then`

Should catch empty User IDs

Comment: _Nz_ is a bit handier:  `If Nz(Me!USER_ID.Value) = "" Then`